# Reporting offensive tags

Tags: discussion, tags

How can offensive tags be reported or flagged in StackOverflow and associated sites?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Flag the question and in the little message box mention that you find the tag(s) on the question offensive and which one(s) specifically you find offensive.

Then it goes to a moderator to deal with.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your reputation level, you also have the right to go in and edit the offensive tag out.  Of course you run the risk that the offender will then try to re-add it.  At that point, follow random's suggestion of flagging the item for administrator attention.